# Shift a graph's isomorphic complement vertices to make it look like its original graph

Tags: graph-theory

So, I was searching for an algorithm to see if you are given given a self-complementary graph(it's isomorphic), how can we shift the vertices of its complement to arrange it to look like the original graph?

Eg. below:
First graph:

[image]

Its complementary graph:

[image]

After moving the second graph's vertices a bit, you get the same image as the first graph:

[image]

Is there an algorithm for this process? If so can you point me in the right direction please? I have searched everywhere and I can't find any.
Thank you.

Comment: Terminology: the second graph is not "the first's graph self-complementary graph", just the first graph's *complement*, which happens to be isomorphic to the original graph because because the original graph is self-complementary.

Comment: You probably want to ask: "If you are given a self-complementary graph, how can we shift the vertices of its complement to arrange it to look like the original graph?". A broader similar question is "If you are given two isomorphic graphs, how can we shift the vertices of one to arrange it to look like the other?"

Comment: @MishaLavrov exactly that, how can this be achieved?

Comment: @bof so do you have any idea on the algorithm to find the right permutation?

Comment: No, I have no idea. Trial and error?

Comment: What I don't understand here is _why_ you want to do this? It seems like you want the layout (coordinates) of the first graph given the second one. However, you already have the first! Are you animating the process, or...

Comment: @gilleain it's a small part of a bigger problem that's being part of a contest. I've figured the algorithm for the rest of the problem, but the last part of the problem basically comes down to this permutation that I don't know how to generate.

Comment: Which contest? Is it still running, or is it over?

Comment: @DanielFischer it's over, I was just curious as I couldn't complete this part of the problem. I just couldn't think of an algorithm to check if a permutation matches its original graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check for an isomorphism between the graphs, it should be as simple as:

1. Say the permutation is $\phi$ = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
2. Permute the edges of the complementary graph by $\phi$
3. Compare these to the original

So, for your example, we have an edge list of (1:3, 1:4, 2:4, 2:5, 3:5) and these are permuted as (1:5, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5) - which is the same as the original.

To permute an edge with $\phi$, just consider it as a mapping that you are reversing. So for edge (1:3),  $\phi$[1] = 1, and $\phi$[3] = 2 which gives you 1:2. In other words, the permutation gives for each vertex (1 to 5) in the original the corresponding vertex in the complementary graph.

I'm aware that there is a more mathematical way to express this as the inverse of the permutation ($\phi^{-1}$ = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]) where you just apply it as a function. That might be more straightforward to use.

Comment: How exactly do you permute (1:3, 1:4, 2:4, 2:5, 3:5) with $ϕ$ to give you (1:5, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5) ? I can't seem to spot how to do that calculation.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was a bit of a roundabout route. I learned about this things a bit pragmatically, rather than mathmatically/formally so my explanation may be a bit off.

Comment: It's a really good explanation, it might work. Now the only thing remains to figure out how to generate $ϕ$ for large graphs, if you have 20+ vertices, doing backtracking on all permutation and for every permutation doing what you discribed it's not feasible. Thank you!